# JBoss EAP migration

Tags: jboss, migration, cxf

I am relatively new to the whole JBoss ecosystem and am migrating an application from EAP 6.4 to EAP 7.1. I keep getting the issue:

`.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYWS0059: Apache CXF library (cxf-core-(version).jar) detected in ws endpoint deployment; either provide a proper deployment replacing embedded libraries with container module dependencies or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it`

where (version) changes on my altered attempts - changing the dependencyManagement in pom.xml.

Below is my dependencyManagement in my pom.xml file - the first is what it was on eap 6.4, the second was me attempting to upgrade it to v 7, and the third is what I have currently, copy-pasted from another application that does work on EAP 7.1:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>6.3.0.redhat-283</version>-->
            <!--<type>pom</type>-->
            <!--<scope>import</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.fuse/jboss-fuse-parent &ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--<groupId>org.jboss.fuse</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>7.0.0.fuse-000191-redhat-1</version>-->
            <!--<type>pom</type>-->
            <!--<scope>import</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <version>7.1.0.GA</version>
            <artifactId>jboss-eap-javaee7-with-spring4</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have also tried updating the jboss-deployment-structure.xml to exclude webservices (which leads no NoClassDefFoundErrors), and have tried adding dependency modules apache.cxf and apache.cxf.impl.

In my eap 7.1 instance, the modules folder has a system/layers/base/org/apache/cxf/main/cxf-core-3.1.12.redhat-1.jar, which is what I believe is clashing with the cxf-core library in my application.

One thing I'm not quite sure of is that the people I took over this application from kept mentioning that it required FUSE, however outside of the fuse BOM in the pom.xml it seems deployed on a standard EAP 6.4 instance so I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

How do I go about ignoring this library or fixing this?

Thanks

EDIT:

The only cxf in the pom is as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
```

Comment: Cannot tell without full pom.xml, but have you tried to mark your cxf dependency as `<scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: Thanks! Added an edit to the bottom of my question. I'll try that out

Comment: camel-cxf scope provided caused other, probably more severe issues. No-go :(